# How to add batch requests handling to Django project?

Tags: python, django

I have an Django application that provide WEB APIs.

I want to add batch requests (send multiple operations in a single HTTP request) handling to it.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: have you looked into [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Also looks like theres an addon to do [bulk operations](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk)

Answer (score 3):

[django-batch-requests](https://github.com/tanwanirahul/django-batch-requests) seems like a reasonable bare-bones solution. [This](https://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/rest-and-batch) article gives a better treatment of how batch requests should probably be done in a REST api - basically, the "POST json describing the request" approach is flawed in the same ways SOAP is - and worse, since it makes the behavior of your REST api inconsistent.

Also, [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) defines a batch requests api if you want something to emulate. They use the SOAP-ish approach.